# Function "main" calls input listener, returns input value but logs undefined. How to make it sync and log input value each time?

Tags: javascript

I have a function named `main`, within which I am calling an input event listener and checking if the user enters valid input. If the input is correct, I am returning the input value to the main function. However, when I attempt to `console.log` the value, it returns as `undefined`. How can I make this function work synchronously in order to achieve the desired outcome, while also noting that I want to `console.log` the input value every time the user inputs a correct value?

*[HTML CODE]*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Demo Code</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <body>
      <form action="" method="get">
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Enter Your Name">
        <label id="error"></label> 
      </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

*[JavaScript Code]*

```
function validator(regex, input) {
  /*This function takes regex and user input and returns true or false*/
  const re = regex;
  return re.test(input);
}

function main() {
  const inputName = document.querySelector('#name');
  const errorName = document.querySelector('#error');

  inputName.addEventListener('input', () => {

    // regular expression string only alphabets and no space
    isValid = validator(/^[a-z]*$/, inputName.value);

    if (isValid) {

      errorName.innerHTML = "Valid Name";
      // it should only returns when isValid is true,
      //  as later I want to use correct inputName.value in some another function
      return inputName.value;
    }
    else {
      errorName.innerHTML = "Invalid Name";
    }

  });
}

let name = main()
console.log(name) // I want to console.log the value every time when inputName value returns the correct name, but in this case it prints undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to console log the value every time when inputName value returns the correct name

Than keep the console.log inside if statement which is inside `input.addEventListener` something like this

````js
if (isValid) {
 Console.log(inputName.value); ...
    }```
````

Answer (score 0):

You need to set it up so the validation will occur *after* the user inputs something into the `name` input field:

```js
const nam=document.getElementById("name"),
  err=document.getElementById("error");
nam.addEventListener("input",ev=>{
 err.textContent="";
 if (nam.value.match(/^[a-z]*$/))
  console.log(nam.value);
 else err.textContent=`${nam.value} does not fulfil the validation-regex (/^[a-z]*$/)`;
});
```

```html
<form action="" method="get">
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Enter Your Name">
  <label id="error"></label> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

### **Please check out this code and let me know if that is what you want**

You can simplify this code even more to make it readable.

```
function main() {
  const inputName = document.querySelector("#name");
  const errorName = document.querySelector("#error");

  inputName.addEventListener("input", () => {
    let isValid = validator(/^[a-z]*$/, inputName.value);
    if (isValid) {
      errorName.innerHTML = "Valid Name";
      console.log(inputName.value);
      return inputName.value;
    } else {
      errorName.innerHTML = "Invalid Name";
    }
  });
  function validator(regex, input) {
    const re = regex;
    return re.test(input);
  }
}
main();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).